# Allowing bigger words to be accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a spelling game for children where empty spaces are highlighted in a grid and clues are given to spell the word correctly by dragging the corresponding letters on the side of the grid.

If you get the word right the space in the grid fades away with the use of "wordglow2". If you get it wrong it glows red with "wordglow4".

This works fine for 3 letter words as I thought these where going to be theonly words I was ever going to use in my grid. Now I have been told it needs to be expanded it some point and when I add bigger words the script acknowledges them after 3 dropped letters, even if it is 5 long.

Here is the code that currently says if (word == 3) then apply styles...

```
            if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
            if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {

                $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass('wordglow2');
                $(right).val('Right!');
                $(right).show();
                audioS.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(wrong).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);
```

I need it to take into consideration, the size of the word and then if it is right do the rest.

http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/cTGGA/20/

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something thinking about why do you need to check `guesses[word].length` here, so yes, fiddle would be great. )

Comment: Maybe you mean letters where you say words? It's like a wheel of fortune type game thing?

Comment: Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/cTGGA/20/ @raina77ow

Comment: No not like that have a look at the fiddle, I will edit the question as I have strayed from the point @Mutahhir

Comment: :) Well, maybe its late, and its just me but that's a confusing game. Can you state more clearly what you require?

Comment: @Mutahhir have you looked at the fiddle

Comment: Yes, I did. :) The problem is I don't get what the problem is that you want to fix. Please re-read and if possible explain it a bit more clearly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you could check the array length against the length of the word.  For example:

```
if (guesses[word].length == word.length) {
```

This would validate that the length of the guesses array was the same as the length of the word they are trying to solve, regardless of whether the word has 3, 4, 5, or more letters.

Comment: You're very welcome.  This is one of my first answers, and I appreciate the "Accept"!